# How to create a dictionary based on Firebase, but values being defined are the children and the values that are defining are parent nodes [Swift]

Tags: swift, firebase, dictionary, firebase-realtime-database

I need to generate a dictionary that is in the format of [States: Representatives]. I have stored a list of representatives with several bits of pertinent information about the representative. It looks like this:

[image]

I need to sort these representatives based on the State value they have in them.

I tried to isolate each of the state values, but it ended up printing out only the entire children snapshot.

```
ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "Redacted for Privacy")
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        print(snapshot.childrenCount) // I got the expected number of items
        let enumerator = snapshot.children
        while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot {
            print(rest.value!)
        }
    })
```

How can I possibly store each and every representative so that they are actually defined by their state? For example, one entry in the Dict might be ALABAMA: [Jo Bonner, Martha Roby, Mike Rogers, Robert B Aderholt, Mo Brooks, Spencer Bachus, Terri A  Sewell]. None of the examples I have found seem to be able to be changed to do this.

I tried using this code:

```
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(6), execute: {
        print("six second delay")
        print("entered function")
        var i: Int = 0
        var x: Int = 0
        while(i < self.repList.count){
            print("i = " + String(i))
            self.ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "Redacted for privacy" + "/" + self.repList[i] + "/" + "State")
            self.ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                print(snapshot.value!)
                let valString = snapshot.value! as? String
                if (valString != nil){
                    self.captured = String(valString!)
                    print("Noice")

                }
                else {
                    print("ya done f***** up")
                }
            })
            while(x < self.stateCongmanDict.count){
                print("x = " + String(x))
                if (self.stateCongmanDict[self.captured] != nil){
                    self.alreadyThere = true
                    break
                }
                x = x + 1
            }
            self.stateCongmanDict[self.captured] = [self.captured]
            i = i + 1
        }
        i = 0
        x = 0
        while (i < self.repList.count){
            print("i restarted = " + String(i))
            self.ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "Redacted for privacy" + "/" + self.repList[i] + "/" + "State")
            self.ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                print(snapshot.value!)
                let valString = snapshot.value! as? String
                if (valString != nil){
                    self.captured = String(valString!)
                    print("Noice")

                }
                else {
                    print("ya done f***** up")
                }
            })
            while(x < self.stateCongmanDict.count){
                print("restarted x = " + String(x))
                if (self.stateCongmanDict[self.captured]! != [""]){
                    self.alreadyThere = true
                    break
                }
                else {
                    var c: Int = 0
                    var capturedDos: String = ""
                    while (c < self.repList.count - 1){
                        print("c = " + String(c))
                        self.ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "Redacted for privacy" + "/" + self.repList[c] + "/" + "State")
                        self.ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                            print(snapshot.value!)
                            let valString = snapshot.value! as? String
                            if (valString != nil){
                                capturedDos = String(valString!)
                                print("Noice")
                            }
                            else {
                                print("ya done f***** up")
                            }
                        })
                        if (capturedDos == self.captured){
                            print("DO YOU SEE ME!!!!")
                            self.stateCongmanDict[capturedDos]?.append(self.repList[i])
                        }
                        c = c + 1
                    }
                }
                x = x + 1
            }
            i = i + 1
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(6), execute: {
            print("six second delay check state")
            print("succeed if seen:" + String(describing: self.stateCongmanDict))
        })
    })
```

Unfortunately it just prints an empty dict:

```
six second delay check state
succeed if seen:
["": ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]]
```

Comment: Can you please tell what is the output of this statement: `print(rest.value!)` ?

Comment: If I remember correctly it just printed out the ALL the children under a name (like "Aaron Schock")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to iterate through the children and then check to see if state already exists in the dictionary or not, so I think you can do something like this (I havent tested it but the idea is same):

```
var dictionary = [String: [String]]()
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        print(snapshot.childrenCount) // I got the expected number of items
        let enumerator = snapshot.children
        while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot {
            print(rest.value!)
            let name = rest.key
            if let value = rest.value as? [String: Any] {
                  let state = value["State"] as? String
                  if var repsArr = self.dictionary[state] as? [String] {
                          repsArr.append(name)
                          self.dictionary[state] = repsArr
                  }else {
                          let newRepsArr = [name]
                          self.dictionary[state] = newRepsArr
                  }
                  print("Dictionary Inside while loop: \(self.dictionary)") //watch dictionary build itself
            }

        }
        print("Dictionary: \(self.dictionary)")
    })
```

Comment: it doesn't print the full dictionary (I think) as I am getting only one value stored in the array portion (value)

Comment: I had added a six second delay

Comment: @PGODULTIMATE if you use just the above code without adding the six second delay , then what is the output?

Comment: It is the same thing - I just checked

Comment: @PGODULTIMATE ok, can you please tell that `while` loop is run the same number of times as the number of representatives in your firebase db i.e `print(rest.value!)` prints all the representatives?

Comment: It only does 99 entries I believe

Comment: @PGODULTIMATE please add the `print("Dictionary Inside while loop: \(self.dicationary)")` and see what does it print for each iteration.

Comment: It prints the same values as if it was outside the loop but just over and over again.

Comment: @PGODULTIMATE I have added this line in the above code `self.dictionary[state] = repsArr` , see the updated answer, and please give your feedback

Comment: Just so that you know (I haven't made the changes yet) I am getting two cautions:

Conditional downcast from '[String]?' to '[String]' does nothing and Variable 'newRepsArr' was never mutated; consider changing to 'let' constant

Comment: I found the problem: I had forgotten to make a reference to the specific node. It was going to my senator node instead.